# Importing JS variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

So in theory this works here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMONmP

But in my Vuejs application I have the JS in an external file (/assets/js/age.js).

In Application.vue I have imported the file;

```
import myAge from '../assets/js/age.js'


export default {
  created() {
    console.log('I am ' + myAge);
  },
}
```

The problem is that {{ myAge }} is showing blank in the template and when I console.log it, the console shows "I am undefined". I know that the path is correct as I can console.log in the .js file and it will output correctly, but I don't understand why it is undefined in my .vue file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, John.

Comment: what and how do you export in age.js?

Comment: exports.myAge = myAge;

Comment: I should be `export default myAge`

Comment: Please show age.js file